# Magento and Moodle Integration

Tags: php, authentication, magento, single-sign-on, moodle

I have a project which requires me to setup an subscription-based online learning site using Moodle. I checked Moodle and it seems that it can handle this by itself. The problem is, the client won't be just selling online courses. He will also be selling books, reviewers, etc.

I figured that Magento would be the best option for selling those items, and keep track of all the sales. I could probably add the online courses as virtual items.

My questions is: Is there a way to fully integrate these two system in terms of authentication and course enrollment?

I mean, would it be possible for someone to:

- Create an account in Magento
- Buy a course in Magento
- Go to Moodle site without logging in (single sign-on)
- Go to the course.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is possible with a moderate effort.

Check my plugins (GPL) for moodle2 that let moodle support [auth](http://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=auth_saml) and [enrolment](http://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=enrol_saml) based on simplesamlphp software.

With those plugins the "moodle part" is done. You can "provisioning/deprovisioning users on courses on the fly", using the user atribute entitlements sent on the saml assertion.

So you only must to add [saml support to Magento](http://cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/sixto-martin-saml-single-sign-on-magento-extension) and develop the logic to add the entitlements to the auth source that you use in your identity provider when a purchase is done.

Edit:

Comment: Thanks @smartin for your brilliant plugins! These are exactly what I need! Can't wait to try them. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @junwafu If you want to see the moodle plugin working there is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlmTJkEG1sw) and a [demo](http://www.yaco.es/uniquid) available. (but is in spanish)

Comment: @junwafu How is your project?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely it seems there are no extensions that bridge Magento with Moodle. You'll have to develop a module yourself :S

Answer (score 0):

To solve the single sign on(SSO) issue you will have to use simpleSAMLphp.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How would you go about integrating simpleSAMLphp into Magento?