# Magento - moodle connection

Tags: php, magento, moodle

I want to sell my moodle courses via magento.

The process flow is as follows:

1. User creates an account in magento (shopping cart).
2. User purchases a course.
3. After purchasing the course the user can login to moodle with the same login details with which the user registered to magento.
4. User should get enrolled to purchased course.

Please help.

Comment: This link will help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763999/magento-and-moodle-integration

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Moodle alot and would recommend using Moodle 2.0 and allowing users to pay for a course that way.

See Here: [How to pay for a course in Moodle 2.0](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=164008)