# Moodle dual external database authentication with magento and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, magento, moodle

Currently I have moodle-wordpress external database authentication. But I need to add another database to authenticate which is in magento. But there is no plugin in moodle to add another database.
How can i add another database?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Develop duplicate plugin (unique usernames)

This can be achieved if you have unique usernames in each system with a bit of development and debugging.

To duplicate the database plug-in copy the auth/db plugin and rename it auth/db2

Then do a search and replace on instances of 'auth_db' to 'auth_db2' and 'auth/db' to 'auth/db2' and tidy up the language strings for plugin name etc.

This should get you about 90% of the way there and then you will need to run some debugging to see what you missed and tidy up the functions until it works.

I have done this successfully in a previous role and it works fine.

### Non-unique username

If you have non-unique usernames then you might need to build a prefix into the new copied plugin to avoid conflicts.

### Use SAML (or other)

This might be another alternative answer based on a [SAML solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763999/magento-and-moodle-integration)